# Disable the "auto" onscreen keyboard in Vista/Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, keyboard, accessibility

I am using a multi-touch HP PC, and I want to disable the on-screen keyboard that pops up when a text input field gets focus.

This is the same keyboard as when you touch the left side of the screen.

Is there a way to disable this keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are not for what was asked.  Wants to know how to close "Tablet PC Input Panel".  Follow instructions below:

To exit Input Panel
When you click the Close button , Input Panel slides back to the edge of the screen. If you want to turn off Input Panel completely so that it is no longer running on your desktop, do the following:

1.Open Input Panel.

2.Click Tools, and then click Exit.

Comment: The answer is unclear. Are you simply explaining how to close Tablet Input Panel in a current session? The question specifically says "disable".

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the Tablet Input Panel?

[image: TIP example]

If so, go to **Tools > Options** and untick **For tablet pen input, show the icon next to the text box**.

Comment: ah, you got it :)

Answer (score 2):

Press **Win + U** to launch the **Ease of Access Center**.

Then click on **Use the Computer without a mouse or keyboard** (most likely the 3rd option in the list).

On the next page clear the box **Use On-Screen Keyboard**.

Click **Apply** and you're done.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a different on screen keyboard. I want the one that pops up when a text input area receives focus. The option you mentioned is already off my default.

Comment: that's called Input Panel, not onscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

To disable it, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Click Uninstall Programs.
3. In the left pane, click Turn Windows Features On Or Off.
4. Clear the Tablet PC Optional Components check box.
5. Click OK.
6. When prompted, click Restart Now and let your computer restart.